# How to customize Y axis cursor formatting in LightningChart ChartXY?

Tags: lightningchart

When you move the mouse over [this line chart](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0017-largeLineChartXY.html?isList=false), you can see the marker on the Y axis showing the current Y value. I want to change the displayed value but have no idea how this element is called in the documentation, if it is described at all.

[image: Chart Y axis marker.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor formatting over a particular axis (Y axis in this case) is controlled over properties of *tick strategy*.

Here's a code snippet how to customize the cursor formatting.

```
chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, ticks => ticks
    .setCursorFormatter((value, range) => `${value.toFixed(1)} W`)
)
```

[image]

As seen in the picture, the cursor formatter is also referenced by the default formatting in cursor result table.